# How do I stop attempting to consume messages off of Kafka when at the end of the log?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a Kafka consumer that I create on a schedule. It attempts to consume all of the new messages that have been added since the last commit was made.

I would like to shut the consumer down once it consumes all of the new messages in the log instead of waiting indefinitely for new messages to come in.

I'm having trouble finding a solution via Kafka's documentation.

I see a number of timeout related properties available in the Confluent.Kafka.ConsumerConfig and ClientConfig classes, including FetchWaitMaxMs, but am unable to decipher which to use. I'm using the .NET client.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Kafka consumer was designed to run indefinitely. There are always way to stop the kafka consumer by just calling the shutdown method, but rebuilding kafka consumer again and again is going to be expensive. This also creates a problem in the kafka server which would start timing out if no consumers are connected to it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I agree Kafka was designed to run indefinitely. However, my requirement is to have it run on a schedule. I have posted the solution I found.

Answer (score 6):

I have found a solution. Version 1.0.0-beta2 of Confluent's .NET Kafka library provides a method called `.Consume(TimeSpan timeSpan)`. This will return null if there are no new messages to consume or if we're at the partition EOF. I was previously using the `.Consume(CancellationToken cancellationToken)` overload which was blocking and preventing me from shutting down the consumer. More here: https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/issues/614#issuecomment-433848857

Another option was to upgrade to version 1.0.0-beta3 which provides a boolean flag on the ConsumeResult object called IsPartitionEOF. This is what I was initially looking for - a way to know when I've reached the end of the partition.

Answer (score 2):

I have never used the .NET client, but assuming it cannot be all that different from the Java client, the `poll()` method should accept a timeout value in milliseconds, so setting that to `5000` should work in most cases.  No need to fiddle with config classes.

Another approach is to find the maximum offset at the time that your consumer is created, and only read up until that offset.  This would theoretically prevent your consumer from running indefinitely if, by any chance, it is not consuming as fast as producers produce. But I have never tried that approach.

Comment: Thanks, Mike. Both of those solutions would work. I was using version 1.0.0-beta2 which unfortunately did not support the Poll() methods. Version 1.0.0-beta3 looks like it supports it. For those interested: https://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/confluent-kafka-dotnet/api/Confluent.Kafka.Consumer.html#Confluent_Kafka_Consumer_Poll